# Datatable Compute Method filter on row number

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, aggregate-functions

I use a query which fetches say 50 records and passes it to a datatable. This record is then displayed in a tabular format. The display has pagination used displaying 10 records at a time. There is a facility to move to next or previous set of record or move forward or backwards by 1 record.

I have to find Min and Max of a column for the set of record currently visible. I am planning to use Compute method but I am not sure if it allows filtering on anything other than the columns in datatable.

Do I have to include row number in my query or is there a better solution (something along the line mentioned below)?

```
CType(dtLineup.Compute("Min(ArrivalDate)", dt.row(2) to dt.row(12)), Date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like your pseudo code in [MSDN on `DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx). You could include a row number in your query, as you said, but an alternative is to add a row number column to your data table and use that in the filter expression.

```
DataColumn col = new DataColumn("rownumber", typeof(int));
col.AutoIncrement = true;
col.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
datatable.Columns.Add(col);
```

Another alternative could be to do paging by linq (Skip-Take) and compute the aggregate function over the returned rows. But that may be a major departure of your current application structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have managed to implement paging using Linq (Skip Take). I have put in a separate question regarding compute method used above here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511238/datatable-compute-method-convert-string-column-to-date). any input would be appreciated.