# Datatable Compute Method Convert string column to date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, aggregate-functions, calculated-columns

I have a column in datatable having dates with format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`. I fill the datatable using the code below which is common for more than 1 select statements so i cannot specify column and their datatype before filling the datatable. Any manipulation after filling the data is acceptable to me.

```
data_adapt = New OracleDataAdapter(query, OraConn)
dt = New DataTable
data_adapt.Fill(dt)
```

For paging i create a copy of the datatable using skip and take as below

```
dtLineupCopy = New DataTable
dtLineupCopy = dtLineup.AsEnumerable().Skip(startRows).Take(pageSize)).CopyToDataTable()
```

Now the issue is when I use Compute method it doesn't treat the column values as date type and returns some random date value from the column instead of minimum value.

```
Arvdate = dtLineupCopy.Compute("Min(Arrivaldate)", "")
```

Is there a way to convert the datatype for the column?

Also tried adding a new column of datetime type but it throws error `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

```
dtLineupCopy.Columns.Add("ArvDate", getType(DateTime), "CONVERT(Arrivaldate, 'System.DateTime')")
```

Data in Arrivaldate column of dtLineupCopy.

22/09/2012 01:02
 27/09/2012 17:01
 1/10/2012 1:02
 13/10/2012 07:26
 14/10/2012 19:47
 20/10/2012 00:00
 20/10/2012 00:00

Comment: The date format should not be a problem for the CONVERT. I suspect that there is some junk in the database, i.e. strings in the `Arrivaldate` column that do not fit the format.

Comment: @GertArnold I have added the data above. Please have a look at the format. Does this has anything to do with culture?

Comment: I can fill a data table with one DateTime column with the values you supplied in some pretty outlandish (for me) cultures. With a string column and a calculated column, even with AM/PM in the time component the CONVERT swallows it all in any culture. Are you sure there is no junk string anywhere in the database table, or are these all values so far?

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry for the late update. Few hours back I tried overriding the default culture with Culture="en-GB" at page level and that worked. So it seems it had to do with culture. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Good for you! Just curious: which culture did you use?

Answer (score 0):

How about converting to date in the query:

```
Min(TO_DATE(Arrivaldate, format_mask)
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: are you sure this would work as an expression in compute method. I tried `dtLineupCopy.Compute("Min(TO_DATE(ETA, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'))", "")` but it throws error.

Comment: No, I was referring to the SQL query variable here: data_adapt = New OracleDataAdapter(query, OraConn). If not you should run through the datatable and do some conversion like CDate(), maybe adding a new date column as CDate(Arrivaldate)

Answer (score 0):

If the query that you pass in results in Arrivaldate being brought back as a string not a date then the preferred option would be to change that query? Instead of selecting Arrivaldate, select:

```
to_date(Arrivaldate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:Mi') as Arrivaldate
```

If somehow that's not an option then you parse the strings afterwards. Doing that within the confines of the `DataTable.Compute` expression means rolling your own parsing date into sortable format function something like ...

```
Arvdate = dtLineupCopy.Compute("Min(Substring(Arrivaldate,7,4) + Min(Substring(Arrivaldate,4,2) + Min(Substring(Arrivaldate,1,2) + ... etc ..... " )) )
```

Comment: Tried this `dtLineupCopy.Compute("Min(Substring(Arvdate,7,4)) + Min(Substring(Arvdate,4,2)) + Min(Substring(Arvdate,1,2))", "")` but it throws an error `Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.`